# combining images in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, image-processing

What can I use in angular to combine 2 images i.e. images 1 and 2 as shown in the demo image below and make it like image 3

[demo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ah7C.jpg)

Comment: you need to create a new canvas and draw the two images on it.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that using pack-manger grunt or gulp.

https://github.com/aslansky/css-sprite